# Python / Kivy - Changing Screen with phone screen orientation (android)

Tags: python, kivy

I haven't found anything on the internet so far, all I want to know is if its possible to change the current screen in kivy depending on the orientation of the phone's screen (Landscape or portrait) and how to do it. or at least a link to a tutorial because I couldn't find one myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way of doing this by recognizing the android device's orientation. However, the following program changes it's contents by comparing the window's height and width. The program's Label changes dynamically, so when the width is greater (landscape mode) it's Label has a different text then when the height is greater (portrait mode). Currently it works on Windows, but unfortunately I don't have a Linux system to build an android version. Theoretically it should work, but i'm not 100% sure.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color


class MainScreen(FloatLayout, Label):

    """MAIN WINDOW CLASS"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0.988, 0.725, 0.074, 1, mode='rgba')
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(size=self.update_rect)

        self.titlos = Label(text="",
                            bold=True,
                            text_size=(None,None),
                            font_size="20sp",
                            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': .85},
                            size_hint_y=None,
                            size = self.size,
                            height=self.texture_size[1],
                            halign="center",
                            valign = "middle",
                            color=(0.055, 0.235, 0.541, 1))

        self.add_widget(self.titlos)
        self.bind(size=self.update_orientation)

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        """FUNCTION TO UPDATE THE RECATANGLE OF CANVAS TO FIT THE WHOLE SCREEN OF MAINSCREEN ALWAYS"""
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def update_orientation(self, *args):
        """FUNCTION TO UPDATE THE SCREEN CONTENTS WHEN THE WINDOW SIZE CHANGES"""
        if self.parent.size[1] > self.parent.size[0]:
            self.titlos.text = "This is\nPortrait\nOrientation"
        else:
            self.titlos.text = "This is Landscape Orientation"

        # This is just for checking. Not essential to the program.
        print("Width:", self.parent.size[0], ", Height:", self.parent.size[1])



class main(App):
    """BUILDING THE APP"""
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main().run()
```

You can use the `update_orientation` function to include whatever you need to change when the orientation changes.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that, but what I meant was if I could make it so that the current screen changes, or the layout changes depending on the orientation, you know how your phone's calculator changes to a scientific one when you flip the phone to landscape mode? that's what i mean

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan That's a very nice question then. I haven't tried this before, but i promise i will look it up. If you find an answer before us, please post it here.

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan I have found an "unorthodox" way to change the screen contents when the orientation changes. The program doesn't actually check if the orientation is Portrait or Landscape but instead it compares the height and the width of the screen. I also haven't tried it on android yet but it works on Windows. Would you be interested in it? I can post it here and maybe you can check it on android.

Comment: sure, post it if you can

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan take a look